# Animation slows down as it ends

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uianimation

I have a translate animation, moving my button from A to B.

That route looks like this:

1) Button slowly accelerates
2) At the middle of animation gets to the peak of it's speed
3) Slows down as it approaches the end

This is my code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:speed
                      delay:delay
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^(void){
                     [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:5];
                     cloud.frame = (CGRectMake(cloud.frame.origin.x,   
cloud.frame.origin.y+900, cloud.frame.size.width, cloud.frame.size.height));

                 }completion:nil];
```

I want my animation to have a same speed all the time.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I thought that this was the default behavior, but try explicitly adding `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear` as one of your options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear` to your animation options, like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:speed
                      delay:delay
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^(void){
                     [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:5];
                     cloud.frame = (CGRectMake(cloud.frame.origin.x,   
cloud.frame.origin.y+900, cloud.frame.size.width, cloud.frame.size.height));

                 }completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanna try setting the "option" parameter to:

```
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
```